# How to convert DotnetNuke Modules created in 4.x to version 5.x

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have around ~40 custom modules and a custom skin on a DotNetNuke site that I have created.  I tried updating it to 5.0 and got a few exceptions.

I want to see what the effort would be to convert a bunch of modules and a skin to work in DotNetNuke 5.0.  I cannot find anything specific using Google.  Any experiences or resources you have had would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to the custom skin, there's a blog post from Nina Meiers that goes into a bit of detail on how to get a [legacy skin to work in DNN 5](http://blogs.ninameiers.com/2008/06/29/DNN+5+Beta+Part+3.aspx). In the end I don't think she got it to work and it doesn't look like it'd be a trivial task however so I'd be prepared to put in some hours to learn how it works under the covers.

I know nothing about the modules however.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/briandukes/archive/2009/02/17/packaging-modules-for-dotnetnuke-5.aspx) is a blog post about packaging modules for DotNetNuke 5.

Also [converting skin package of DotNetNnuke 4.x to DotNetNuke 5.x](http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2009/07/converting-skin-package-of-dotnetnnuke.html) seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When I was testing my site to upgrade to DNN5, all but one of my custom modules worked without changing a thing. Our skin worked fine as well.  So one skin and 8 or 9 modules worked great.  The broken module has a dependency on a third-party module I am waiting on an update to.